# Write an application that allows a user to enter any number of student test scores until the user enters 999

Tags: python

> Write a python application that allows a user to enter any number of student test scores until the user enters 999. If the score entered is less than 0 or more than 100, display an appropriate message and do not use the score. After all the scores have been entered, display the number of scores entered and the arithmetic average.

I am having trouble breaking the loop when the score entered is less than 0 or more than 100.

The code I have is

```
total_sum = 0
count = 0
avg = 0
numbers = 0

while True:
    num = input("Enter student test score: ")

    if num == "999":
        break
    if num < "0":
        break
        print("Number is incorrect")

    if num > "100":
        break
    print ("Number is incorrect")

    total_sum += float(num)
    count += 1
    numbers = num

avg = total_sum / count

print("The average is:", avg)
print("There were " +str(count) + " numbers entered")
```

Comment: Convert it to a number and *then* it will be easy to tell if it's outside the required bounds.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. You want to compare *numbers*, not strings. Try using `float(input(...))`
2. `break` will break out of the loop in exactly the same way for numbers under 0, above 100, or for the "finished" token 999. That's not what you described that you want. Rather, for "incorrect numbers" just print the message, and don't add the numbers and counter...But no need to break the loop, amirite?
3. You've got an indentation problem for the `< 100` case. Your `print` is missing an indentation.
4. No need to have `avg = 0`
5. `numbers` isn't used

Try something like -

```
total_sum = 0
count = 0

while True:
    num = float(input("Enter student test score: "))

    if num == 999:
        break
    
    elif num < 0 or num > 100:
        print("Number is incorrect")

    else:
        total_sum += num
        count += 1

avg = total_sum / count

print("The average is:", avg)
print("There were " +str(count) + " numbers entered")
```